# How to optimize router in nodejs koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router

I use koa to create a nodejs application, and I try to optimize.

app.js

```
'use strict';
const Koa = require("koa");
const app = new Koa();
const Router = require("koa-router");
const router = new Router();

const stuff = require("./router/stuff.js");
router.use("/stuff", stuff.routes());
//more routers like above
const home = require("./router/home.js");
router.use(home.routes());

app.use(router.routes(), router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(port);
```

There're some router files in folder `router`, such as `stuff.js`, `home.js`, `client.js`

stuff.js

```
'use strict';
const router = require("koa-router")();
router
    .get("/", async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.render("stuff", {

        });
    })
module.exports = router;
```

home.js

```
'use strict';
const router = require("koa-router")();
router
    .get("/", async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.render("home", {

        });
    })
module.exports = router;
```

client.js

```
'use strict';
const router = require("koa-router")();
router
    .get("/", async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.render("client", {

        });
    })
module.exports = router;
```

I think the way I wrote is still very amateurish, how to optimize it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I am using the following solution

app.js

```
'use strict';
const Koa = require("koa");
const app = new Koa();
const router = require("./router");
router(app);
app.listen(port);
```

in folder `router`, add `index.js` with following code

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = (app) => {
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(file => {
    if (file === 'index.js') { return; }
    const route = require(`./${file}`);
    app.use(route.routes()).use(route.allowedMethods());
  });
}
```

Other router files are the same, e.g. `home.js`

```
'use strict';
const router = require("koa-router")();
router
    .get("/", async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.render("home", {

        });
    })
module.exports = router;
```